# briefcase packaging with streamlit ,localhost connection issue briefcase run command

Tags: localhost, streamlit, beeware

briefcase packaging with streamlit running successfully in "briefcase dev" command but shows , localhost refused to connect problem.

It runs without any issues opening in briefcase dev command- automatically allocating port.

I disbaled proxies ,restarted,even made as an installer and installed and checked,but in production this connect issues comes.

I expect it to run localhost by automatically allocating ports ,like when i got output when i ran briefcase dev command

Comment: This will probably require some discussion, so please create an issue on the [Briefcase GitHub page](https://github.com/beeware/briefcase/issues). Make sure you include the full error message.